# Conditional formatting of cells inside renderDataTable

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a mini Shiny app that shows a tiny table that is editable by the user. I was wondering how to add the following functionality to this table:

Change the background for the whole row to yellow if the last cell of that row (column 'Comment') contains (among other things) the string “for yellow” but make the row green if the last cell contains the string "for green". Those two strings will never appear in the same cell together.

My current code (below) has an issue: if I have some other text in the "Comment" column - besides my target strings "for yellow" or "for green" - the formatting goes away. I'd like it to stay there even if other strings are also present in the text of the last cell.

Thank you so much!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

# ________________________________________________________________________________________
### UI code ####

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "DataTable"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(title = "Edit and Export",
      DT::dataTableOutput("o_my_table", width = "600px")))
)

# _________________________________________________________________________________
### SERVER code ####

server <- function(input, output) {

  ### Generate an example table ####
  my_data <- data.frame(
    Order = 1:3, Name = c("John", "Mary", "Paul"),
    Date = as.Date(c("2020-03-01", "2020-03-5", "2020-03-06")),
    Amount = c(100, 150, 200), Paystatus = c("Yes", "No", "Yes"),
    Comment = c(NA, "for yellow", "for green"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  ### Define datatable ####

  output$o_my_table <- DT::renderDataTable({

    datatable(my_data,
              extensions = "Buttons",         # for table export
              editable = list(target = "cell", disable = list(columns = 1)),
              options = list(dom = "Bfrtip",
                             autoWidth = FALSE,
                             buttons = list(
                               list(extend = 'excel',
                                    title = 'My Data',
                                    text = 'Export data',
                                    exportOptions = list(modifier = list(page = 'all')))),
                             columnDefs = list(list(width = "180px", targets = 1:3)))
    ) %>%
      formatStyle('Comment', target = 'row',
                  backgroundColor = styleEqual("for yellow", 'yellow')) %>% 
      formatStyle('Comment', target = 'row',
                  backgroundColor = styleEqual("for green", 'green'))

  })

  ### Define proxy datatable (needed for editable event) ####
  proxyTable_my_table <- dataTableProxy("o_my_table")

  ### Observe edit cell of table ####
  observeEvent(input$o_my_table_cell_edit, {

    info <- input$o_my_table_cell_edit
    i <- info$row # get row number
    j <- info$col # get column number
    v <- info$value

    # my_data dataframe is being updated:
    my_data[i, j] <<- v  # global assignment should be ok because my_data is inside our server
    replaceData(proxyTable_my_table, my_data, resetPaging = FALSE)
  })
}

# ________________________________________________________________________________________
### Return a Shiny app object ####
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I think that all of this can be made with functions of the `DT` package, that you already use. Check the function `formatCurrency` to put dollar sign for example. See [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html) for a recap of the functions

Comment: @bretauv Thank you! Got the currency sorted out!

Comment: @bretauv I was able to get the cell in the last column to change the background color using formatStyle('Comment', backgroundColor = styleEqual("for yellow", 'yellow')) . However, if that cell contains also some other string, e.g. "Comment text 1, for yellow" then it doesn't work. How can I make it change the background if it's one of the several strings in that last column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with the `styleContain` function below:

```
library(DT)

styleContain <- function(string, color){
  JS(sprintf("value === null || value.match(/\\b%s\\b/) === null ? '' : '%s'", 
             string, color))
}

my_data <- data.frame(
  Order = 1:3, Name = c("John", "Mary", "Paul"),
  Date = as.Date(c("2020-03-01", "2020-03-5", "2020-03-06")),
  Amount = c(100, 150, 200), Paystatus = c("Yes", "No", "Yes"),
  Comment = c(NA, "xxx for yellow", "for green"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

datatable(my_data) %>%
  formatStyle('Comment', target = 'row',
              backgroundColor = styleContain("for yellow", 'yellow'))
```

---

## EDIT

The previous code does not work as expected if one uses two `formatStyle`. Here is a fix:

```
library(DT)

styleContain <- function(string, color){
  JS(sprintf("value === null || value.match(/\\b%s\\b/) === null ? value : '%s'", 
             string, color))
}

my_data <- data.frame(
  Order = 1:3, Name = c("John", "Mary", "Paul"),
  Date = as.Date(c("2020-03-01", "2020-03-5", "2020-03-06")),
  Amount = c(100, 150, 200), Paystatus = c("Yes", "No", "Yes"),
  Comment = c(NA, "xxx for yellow", "for green"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

datatable(my_data) %>%
  formatStyle('Comment', target = 'row',
              backgroundColor = styleContain("for yellow", 'yellow')) %>%
  formatStyle('Comment', target = 'row',
              backgroundColor = styleContain("for green", 'green'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much - it's ALMOST working. However, it's not working for 2 conditions together (for yellow and for green). I tried to repeat your formatStyle code (last 2 lines) with ("for green", 'green') inside. But then the coloring works only for the last condition. Then I tried to pass vectors (see the code in the next line) - but then the table doesn't appear at all: styleContain(c("for yellow", "for green"),                                                 c('yellow', 'green'))).

Comment: Would it be possible to somehow change your styleContain function so that it works with two vectors (a vector of strings and a vector of colors)?

Comment: @user3245256 See my edit, I fixed that. However I don't understand how it works ^^

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. As I mentioned in my comment earlier - it only reacts to the bottom line (in your example - green). It ignores yellow.

Comment: @user3245256 For me it works. I modified the `styleContain` function. Are you sure you have copied it?